# Can't run vagrant provision for Laravel Homestead/Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm running `vagrant global-status`

Getting the homestead machine id and running `vagrant provision <id>`.

This gives me the error

```
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:194:in `active_machines': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:108:in `with_target_vms'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:34:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:249:in `cli'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.0/bin/vagrant:166:in `<main>'
```

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to Vagrant 1.6.1 if anyone has similar problem.

Comment: Please mark you own answer as correct, so it doesn't seem there is no solution to the problem.